# PWA on Xbox, service worker registration causing controller input to stop working

Tags: uwp, progressive-web-apps, xbox

I'm building a Progressive Web App to run on Xbox. I have a simple UWP app with a webview that loads the PWA. When the app is first run after install from the Store, the controller input does not work. Exiting the app and relaunching it fixes the issue, but the issue returns if the app is uninstalled/reinstalled or the Xbox is restarted.

Since it's a PWA it's registering a service worker. Disabling the service worker all together fixes controller issue. I would prefer to utilize a service worker for caching content and improving performance, so the service worker is not optional.

Anyone have any insight into why registration of the service worker would cause the input to stop working?

Comment: May I know the version of your xbox device and your project?

Comment: Xbox One latest version. The project is a Vue.js project, latest version vue-cli (which uses Workbox). UWP wrapper built in the last build of VS 2019.